# UITextView add ...more button at the end of visible text

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

UITextView add ...more button at the end of visible text like on facebook.
I am sorry if it already mentioned somewhere. Specifically I am interested how to count position of the end of visible text with wrapping words

Answer (score 0):

1 . Check UItextView size base on text and Font:

```
// return the size for UITextView for both IOS7 and IOS6
-(CGSize) getSizeWithMaxLabelSize:(CGSize) maxLabelSize forTextViewWithText:(NSString *) text
{
CGSize expectedLabelSize;
CGSize maximumLabelSize = maxLabelSize;
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(@"6.2")) {
    NSDictionary *stringAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:EPCommentViewFontSize] forKey: NSFontAttributeName];
    CGRect rect =[text boundingRectWithSize:maximumLabelSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:stringAttributes context:nil];
    expectedLabelSize = rect.size;
    expectedLabelSize.height = ceilf(expectedLabelSize.height);
    expectedLabelSize.width  = ceilf(expectedLabelSize.width);
} else {
    expectedLabelSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:EPCommentViewFontSize] constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
}
  return expectedLabelSize;
}
```

2 . Compare your UITextView height with expectedLabelSize.height to show `ViewMore` or not

3 . Change UITextView frame.size.height when touched viewMore

```
CGRect frame = _textView.frame;
frame.size.height = [self getSizeWithMaxLabelSize:CGSizeMake(_textView.frame.size.height, NSIntegerMax) forTextViewWithText:_textView.text].height;
_textView.frame = frame;
```

Comment: Yes. I sow this answer. But I am interested how to count position for more button if text in this line isn't to the end of line. (For example: possible solution would be to get last line width inside uitextview)

Comment: just getSize to current line